# pytorch_lightning.metrics cannot be installed

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to `pip install pytorch_lightning.metrics` on colab, but I keep getting this error:

> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytorch_lightning.metrics (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytorch_lightning.metrics

I have installed `pytorch-lightning` and `pip install pytorch-lightning==1.5.1`, but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I believe `pytorch_lightning` doesn't have any API regarding any metrics. It's `torchmetrics`.

They mentioned in [document](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), you can use `torchmetrics` within `pytorch_lightning`. As you are using `pip`, to install: `pip install torchmetrics`